# How to run a task in background at a fixed time in xamarin ios?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am working in xamarin ios. In my app I want to run a task in background at a fixed time. Means I want to run the background task at 12:00 PM (in afternoon) everyday only if app is in idle in background. How can I do this with help of backgrounding in xamarin ios.

Comment: well I guess c# scheduler should work don't you agree?

Comment: There is no way to execute in the background  at a specific time in iOS.

Comment: Why you want to do this, app just have limited time running background task. Can local notification meet your requirement?